# Invalid credentials on Here API endpoints

Tags: here-api

The `/geocode` endpoint is returning a 401 even when valid credentials are supplied.

The following request:

```
GET /6.2/geocode.json?app_code=MY_APP_CODE&amp; app_id=MY_APP_ID&amp; searchtext=test HTTP/1.1
Host: geocoder.api.here.com
cache-control: no-cache
```

returns:

```
<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials">
    <Details>invalid credentials for MY_APP_ID</Details>
</ns2:Error>
```

I'm on a Freemium plan and I get the above response when I use my `app_id` & `app_code`.

**EDIT:** It seems the demo credentials are domain specific, adding a `Referer` header with `https://developer.here.com` as value the request succeeds. But after swapping in `app_id` & `app_code` with my own credentials (not touching any other parameter) I suddenly get a 401 (essentially ruling out the possibility that some of the other parameters are borking the request).

Answer (score 0):

Demo App ID and Code are set as domain specific and has expiration date set. So it need not necessarily work in your browser.  You should use your own credentials. Using my own credentials for the below example query I am able to get the response.

```
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=200%20S%20Mathilda%20Sunnyvale%20CA&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&gen=9
```

Response:

```
Response    
MetaInfo    
Timestamp   "2019-02-05T13:10:09.436+0000"
View    
0   
_type   "SearchResultsViewType"
ViewId  0
Result  
0   
Relevance   1
MatchLevel  "houseNumber"
MatchQuality    
State   1
City    1
Street  
0   0.9
HouseNumber 1
MatchType   "pointAddress"
Location    
LocationId  "NT_nL.dzNwdSJgdcF4U8dYEiC_yADM"
LocationType    "address"
DisplayPosition 
Latitude    37.37634
Longitude   -122.03405
NavigationPosition  
0   {…}
MapView 
TopLeft {…}
BottomRight {…}
Address 
Label   "200 S Mathilda Ave, Sunn…CA 94086, United States"
Country "USA"
State   "CA"
County  "Santa Clara"
City    "Sunnyvale"
District    "Heritage District"
Street  "S Mathilda Ave"
HouseNumber "200"
PostalCode  "94086"
AdditionalData  […]
```

Comment: Replicated this request and still getting a 401. Account is active and using correct credentials (not domain locked). Seems like an account related issue.

Comment: Did you try with your app credentials?

Comment: Yes, that was literally the first thing I did before writing this question. Additionally, I was able to successfully do the query using the demo credentials (by setting the `Referer` header to `https://developer.here.com`) but after swapping in my `app_id` & `app_code`, not touching any other parameter, the endpoint started returning 401.

Comment: Since the problem is specific to your appi_id and code you can try sending email to selfservesupport@here.com with your query(providing your app id and code as well)